# Is it possible to make the help center easier to find for new users?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, help-center

As a regular user, I have had trouble finding our help center and guidelines when I am trying to assist new users.  I am sure that most of them don't even look or know that these exist on the site, especially since feels a little hidden.  Is it possible to have our help center more easily findable from the main page?  Possibly with a "Are you new here?" kind of thing to direct the users to what is expected before they make a post?  Or perhaps I am blind and it is already readily available?

Comment: The help center is accessible by clicking on the question mark icon at the top of every page.  What do you suggest be done to make it *more* accessible?

Comment: Another one, for those unable to locate the question mark for some reason. Google "math stack exchange help center", and see the first search result, which is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/help). Also, when a user asks their first question there is a dialog box that opens up when they start their question, which has some pretty clear instructions ("Don't just copy a textbook problem!" , "Summarize the problem", "Provide details and any research"), so they do get to know what is expected when they start writing their post. We still don't get questions following these, though.